# I had my exhaust replaced and my engine started humming then seized

Tags: engine, exhaust

a while ago I decided to fix my whole exhaust from the headers to the tailpipes. After looking I spent around 2 grand on parts alone ( I made sure they fit) originally I was gonna replace the exhaust system myself as I had a friend who was gonna help. Before we even got started we noticed that the bolts inside the headers were rusted and stuck so I decided to take it to a shop because I didn’t want the bolts to snap off and cause issues. After finally finding a place with a agreeable price I fix my exhaust which took about two days give or take. I finally got my car back... for a total of two weeks. I took time off from work and decided to go on vacation about 7hrs into this road trip I notice my engine starts humming, sputtering, and then finally seizing. I had to put it on a uhaul and take it to a shop. The mechanic there said I’d need a new engine and that there was metal flakes in my oil. I was wondering if anyone know how this could happen and if it’s related to me changing my exhaust.

Comment: Did the engine still have the correct oil level in after it seized?

Comment: Does the car have a turbocharger?

Comment: The car does not have a turbo charger or any supercharger. Also yes the oil level was still the same after the seize.

Comment: Did the oil pressure warning light illuminate prior to the engine seizing?

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s not related to changing the exhaust.

This is down to servicing and maintenance. Questions like the following:

When did you last do a filter and oil change?

Did you check the fluid levels before leaving on your trip?

Things like coolant, oil, brake fluid and even screenwash are simple checks to do weekly.

Doing these checks prior to a long trip can save a lot of time and money. And it is one reason truck drivers do an inspection of the tractor and trailer as they hook up prior to leaving.

When I am doing a long trip I will check the levels etc and have needed work done prior to the trip. One reason some cars are only fit for scrap at less than 100k and others do two or three times that.

Of course, the oil level may have been correct and it was a catastrophic failure that just happened but still, that is not due to changing the exhaust.

Comment: Hi, yeah i had my fluids flushed and changed prior to the long trip!

Answer (score 0):

Your engine likely overheated. It is unlikely to be an exhaust problem - a plugged exhaust just gives bad engine performance, it doesn't overheat the engine. Did your engine coolant light turn on? What was it at? Do you still have coolant in the reservoir?